# Game running at 18 fps in exported jar, and 40 fps in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm currently making a 3d game in Java. My problem is when I run it through Eclipse, I'm getting about 40 fps, which is fine. Though when I run it in an exported jar file, I'm getting 18 fps?

I'm not really sure what's wrong, does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: I once had a low fps issue happen to me where my eclipse was running stuff with Java 6 and when I exported it, my system ran it with Java 5...

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that would be my problem, because I only have Java 6 on my computer.

Comment: How do you talk to your 3D engine?  You may have to need a DLL to get the best performance, which is present in eclipse but not made available to the exported jar.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without more info but some possibilities are:

- different JVM being used by Eclipse than your default system JVM
- different command-line parameters (especially ones relating to graphics) between your commandline invocation and your Eclipse run profile
- copies of the application still 'live' within Eclipse and stealing resources from the external copy